# Core Data and User Defaults in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, singleton, nsuserdefaults

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm working on my first app for the App Store. I have a data model working in Core Data, but I want to have a singleton for user settings and a reference to the current project. I'm having trouble getting a singleton to work in Core Data. I've gotten it to kinda work with User Defaults but it seems clunky to use Core Data AND User Defaults. Does anyone else do it this way?

ps. Are there any good general references for use of predicates in Swift? I haven't found one.

Comment: Why should it be clunky to use both CoreData AND NSUserDefaults? I store data in CoreData and user defined application settings in NSUserDefaults.